# sign jar file with ssl certificate .crt file used for https?

Tags: java, applet

I have bought SSL certificate.I have two .cert files with me.
I want to sign my Jar file so that i can run the applet in the browser.
Can i use the same certificate

Regards
Ramandeep

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [page](http://garrettreid.com/2010/sign-an-applet-jar-with-an-existing-ssl-certificate/)
which outline the steps to use.

Basically

```
java -cp not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder your-new-keystore-password-here yourdomain.tld.key yourdomain.tld.crt
```

This will leave you with a yourdomain.tld.jks file, which you can then go ahead and sign your applet with:

jarsigner -keystore yourdomain.tld.jks -keypass your-new-keystore-password-here applet.to.sign.jar yourdomain.tld

using the link at http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/

Comment: I don't see how this can work unless the CA enabled code-signing for the certificate, or unless it's a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. SSL certificates and code-signing certificates signed by CAs aren't the same. When you purchase it, you say what it's for, and the CA restricts it to that use.

Comment: Hi Thanks , I just went through some code signing certificate providers. What does compatibility means?
whether my jar will run on all the browsers and on all Operating system

Comment: do you know any certificate provider . which gives trail version :)

Comment: I don't know what some unknown 'code signing certificate providers' mean by 'compatible'. Ask them. If by 'trail version' you mean 'trial version', the question is off topic.